# Can't understand this script. bash <<(curl -s http://xxx.com)

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, curl

In a rails book, the author wrote the script to install ruby rvm.

`bash <<(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)`

But I don't understand how it works. Could you explain this?

Comment: As a sidenote, pasting in commands that download then execute *untrusted* scripts off the internet is bad practise.

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully That was my first thought as well. I wonder, if the author wrote about the security implications, e.g. if beginrescueend.com falls into the hand of a domain grabber ~ 10 years in the future. He should have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a << operator (here document) but it is not what is used here.

You have first an input redirection `<` which says pick the input from the following argument then there is the `<(command)` known as process substitution which says replace that by a file descriptor containing the output of the command.

This command could have been written

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

but is just a convoluted way of doing:

```
curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm | bash
```

Answer (score 4):

`one <<(two)` runs the command `two` and pipes its output into `one`. The more common way of writing it is `two | one`, so your command can also be written:

```
curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm | bash
```

That link is broken now, but the website [says](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) to use this instead:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

`curl` outputs what it downloads, so this downloads the file at `get.rvm.io` and pipes its contents to bash. If you just run the `curl` command by itself you can see its a `bash` script that downloads and installs rvm

Comment: Using pipe `|` is more familiar to me. Why did he use the weird syntax. Is using that a trend?

Comment: One more thing. How do you pronounce << operator? Is it called `pipe` either?

Comment: @Benjamin `<<` is the [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) operator. `foo < <(bar)` is mostly equivalent to `bar | foo`, but with a few differences that don't matter here: mainly, with `< <(…)`, `foo` executes in the main shell environment, and the command returns when `foo` returns, whereas with a pipe, `foo` executes in a subshell and the pipeline waits for both commands to complete. (That's in bash, the behavior is closer in ksh and zsh.)

Comment: @Gilles. wow. unexpected comment. that's a good point. thank you.